# Empty lookup column source

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

I have to maintain a Sharepoint site and I have some lookup column with empty "Get information from" data source when I go in the Site Columns/Edit Column :

[image]

Those Column present a list Parameter filtered by Content Type : in the Parameter list there is content type Country, Industry, Colors, etc.. and each of those column (used in view/new/edit form) have "empty data source"...

The real problem is that I have to add a category in the Parameter table and add it to a form but the only choice I have when I add a lookup column is the full parameter list...

How can I create a column like those "empty hidden filtered" existing one ?

Comment: looks like this list is created from list template which breaks lookup column like this.

Comment: Solution will be deleting and recreating this column.

Comment: No, because if I delete the column and recreate it as a lookup with the parameter list as source then all the items, Country, Industry, Colors, etc.. will appear in the drop-down on the form...

Comment: Can you simplify your ask in question. its difficult to understand. I am not sure what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figure out what's happening : it's a Plumsail Cross-site Lookup with single value field... (The problem is that a lot of functionality are not anymore available with that non standard thing :( )